# Scraping Naukri

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape https://www.naukri.com/information-technology-jobs-in-hyderabad-secunderabad-secunderabad for number of pages. I am trying to get company name, designation and skills. I have used inspect and copy xpath. I am facing issue to click next button multiple times and getting data.

```
for i in range(1,21):
    company_name.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div[4]/div[2]/section[2]/div[2]/article['+str(i)+']/div[1]/div/div/a[1]').text)
    time.sleep(3)
    designation.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div[4]/div[2]/section[2]/div[2]/article['+str(i)+']/div[1]/div/a').text)
    time.sleep(3)
    skills.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div[4]/div[2]/section[2]/div[2]/article['+str(i)+']/ul').text)
```

Comment: Hey could you give us more details about the error? Is it not clicking on the button at all or is there some sort of error being thrown?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following xpath for clicking next:

```
while True:
    next_page_btn = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='pagination mt-64 mb-60']//div/child::*")
    if len(next_page_btn) < 1:
        print("No more pages left")
        break
    else:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, '/information-technology-jobs-in-hyderabad-secunderabad-2'))).click()//or use partial link text
```

Answer (score 0):

You no need to click the next button to go to the next page.

https://www.naukri.com/information-technology-jobs-in-hyderabad-secunderabad-10

https://www.naukri.com/information-technology-jobs-in-hyderabad-secunderabad-20

If you observe the above URLs the page navigation number given at the end of each URL, that's how they separated.

Inorder to access all search result pages you need to iterate through a range and format the number to the URL and scrape the data.

Ex:
for ii in range(1, 1000):
URL = "https://www.naukri.com/information-technology-jobs-in-hyderabad-secunderabad-{}".format(ii)
Your Extractor Here.